# spring 5.1.0.RC1 maven 3.8 java 10 transaction not found

Tags: spring-data-jpa, maven-3, java-10

my problem is exactly that :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [main/resources/ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
```

my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>testbdd3</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo1</id>
        <name>central repository</name>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring</id>
        <name>spring depository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180725.0427</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

my dependence tree

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testbdd3 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ testbdd3 ---
[INFO] test:testbdd3:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.197:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.4.0-b180725.0427:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.8.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total 

time: 1.015 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-14T16:30:11+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/54M
[INFO]
```

---

I try to make running a app that run data-jpa to store data to an h2 database

I use spring-data 2.1.0.RC1 that is compatible with spring-* 5.1.0.RC1

I have intelliJ IDEA 2018.1 with JDK-10.0.1

so why javax/transaction/SystemException is missing even it is in the dependency graph as javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile and in the module-info

my module-info

```
open module testbdd3 {
requires spring.context;
requires spring.core;
requires spring.tx;
requires spring.data.jpa;
requires spring.aop;
requires spring.beans;
requires spring.data.commons;
requires spring.expression;
requires spring.jcl;
requires spring.jdbc;
requires spring.orm;
requires java.sql;
requires java.persistence;
requires org.hibernate.commons.annotations;
requires hibernate.entitymanager;
requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
requires java.activation;
requires java.transaction;
requires h2;

exports fr.certytech.print.bll;
}
```

I think I put to many things in my module-info, however, I'll remove stuff from it when it will work.

my ApplicationContext.xml look like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:datasource.properties" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
    <property name="url"    value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${pass}" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxTotal" value="8"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>fr.testbdd.bo</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <!--<prop key="showSql">true</prop>-->
            <prop key="generateDdl">create-drop</prop>
            <!--<prop key="database">H2</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>-->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<jpa:repositories
    base-package="fr.testbdd.dao"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
    />
</beans>
```

Comment: IMHO, if I were you, I would have given Java11 a try, a cleaner world for Java EE modules. Yet do check out these links  - [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585906), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385846/hibernate-5-issue-with-jdk-9), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529510/spring-datajpatest-do-not-load-javax-transaction-systemexception-with-java-9), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244184/java-9-hibernate-and-java-sql-javax-transaction), [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515230/hibernate-java-9-and-systemexception)

Comment: thanks for the help but unfortunatly I've already read most of this post. when jdk11 will pass RC1 (in 2 day) I will DL it and try it.